# Why is the work done on a spring obeying Hooke's Law $(1/2) F x$ and not $(1/2) Fx^2$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, work, potential-energy, spring

[image]

The answer to the question is shown as B, whereas I believe it should be C. Why is this so?

Comment: For starters, did you check if $(1/2)Fx^2$ has dimension of work?

Comment: In order for $F$ to extend the spring by $x$, how is that related to properties of the spring (i.e. $k$).

Comment: Why do you think it should be C?  What's your reasoning?

Comment: Yes, I checked. The work done is indeed that. It's related to the spring for the question is telling you that it's a normal spring that obeys Hooke's law. Otherwise it is possible for less force to be exerted while spring is stretched. It's just a clarification.

Comment: @ArthGupta, you seem to be simply not noticing a "trick" in the answer formulation. Could you please explain, as garyp requests as well, why you believe it should have been C?

Comment: The definition of work done by a spring according to Hooke's law, is
$$W=\frac{1}{2}kx^2$$
where $k$ is a constant with units of Newtons per meter. Here, answer *C* has the work done as $W=F_{\text{max}}x^2$. What units is $F_{\text{max}}$ in? It isn't the same as $k$.

Comment: Look at the options more carefully.   **C** is *not* the definition of work on a spring.

Comment: @Garyp thanks for the help. I see how the question is trying to 'trick' the reader. Yes, C is not the answer.

Comment: The definition of work is also Force*Displacement, why can't the same principle be applied here? Is it because of the resistance offered by the spring?

Comment: 'Tricky' questions can weed out the more observant students, but they don't necessarily test *all* student's knowledge of the physics. They can tend to frustrate the less observant. A better question would have been something like "What two expressions represent the work done on a spring?".

Comment: "*The definition of work is also Force x Displacement, why can't the same principle be applied here?*" Well, it *can* be used - but what expression for force would you put in here? The force is growing during the displacement until it reaches $F_{max}$. It is not just one value (not constant), so although correct, this relationship is not directly usable in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could understand the formula by looking at it from this perspective. The spring has a natural resistance to force applied on it.

Hence, according to Hooke's Law, F = -kx

Now, the work done to compress this spring by an infinitesimally small amount, say dx is given by W = (-kx).dx

Now, the total work done to change the length by a distance x can be obtained by integrating the above formula within the limits of 0 and x resulting in the formula specified.

If you don't understand that, a simpler way of interpreting it is that, over the course of doing work, the force doesn't remain constant but instead varies linearly since it is proportional to displacement, x. So we can can consider the average force over the distance x to be simply half the maximum value. i.e. $F_{average} = (1/2)kx$. Now the potential energy stored in the spring can be obtained using $U = F_{average}x = F_{max}x/2$

Comment: I was with you until the last sentence. And I assume you don't mean "by a distance k".

Comment: @Mike Dunlavey Could the recommend the correction I should make?

Comment: I could, but it would be better if you did it yourself.

Comment: I'm assuming the variable change is all you meant. Sorry, I used standard conventions I was taught by accident. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: In the last sentence, what does trigonometry have to do with it?

Comment: I'm merely stating that force is parallel to displacement at all positions of  the spring. I've edited my answer to include that.

Comment: But $cos(0)$ is $1$, not $1/2$, and the energy in the spring is equal to the work done on the spring, which is $(F_{average} x)$ or $(F_{max} x)/2$ as you said.

Comment: yes that's the point. It's 1 of course. So if you substitute the value of average force in the potential equation you would get the desired formula. The half comes from average force not the trig value

Comment: OK, so in your last sentence, two things: First, since there's no angle involved, the cosine function is just a distraction. Second, when you put $F$, it's confusing whether you mean $F_{average}$ or $F_{max}$. I want to give an upvote, but it's not clear yet.

Comment: + Good. I edited the math a little bit. I recommend [*MathJax*](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It's pretty nifty.

Answer (score 1):

F_ initial = 0 because spring is relaxed.
F_max is the Y coordinate of the stress/strain triangle at point e on x axis.
So the work is = F average x e.

W = (F_i + F_m)e/2 = (0+ F_max)e/2.

$ W = F_max. e/2 $

Or we could just calculate the area of triangle:

base x height/ 2.

Area of force x displacement =   $w =
e . F_max/2$.